# Main Page Login also logs user into Wordpress section

Tags: wordpress, authentication, dreamweaver

We have a site with a members-only section and WordPress in a subdirectory.  Some of the members-only pages, forms, etc. are outside of WP.  We created a Member Login form on our homepage using Dreamweaver 5.5.  Is there a way to have WordPress accept that main login so that a member doesn't need to login again when going to a WP member-only page?  Thanks for any help you can be in pointing me in the right direction.  I know just enough PHP to be dangerous.  Let me know if you would like to see the DW login code.

Comment: Actually, do you mean you want to replace the default Wordpress login page with the custom page you have made in Dreamweaver?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are talking about creating your own custom template for a Wordpress page.

You can use the page you generated from Dreamweaver by renaming its extension to .php, unless it already is. Move it to the /wp-content/themes/yourtheme folder, where yourtheme is your currently active theme. On the top of the template, add these lines:

```
<?php
//
// Template Name: Login Form
//
?>
```

Go to Wordpress Dashboard > Pages > Add New. Add a page called 'Login' or whatever you need, select 'Login Form' as the Template under Page attributes, and you Publish.

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates

Comment: anuragbh,
Thanks for such a quick response! It appears, though that it would still require a second login to get into WordPress (actually, I'm getting a fatal error when my script calls a <?php require_once('../Connections/iama_test.php'); ?> so I haven't been able to test it online.

Comment: My hope is to add some code to the login form, that will be preserved when a user goes to a WordPress member-only page.  If you want to browse the beta site, I can send you a link, although I'm not sure I should publish it here.

Comment: In that case, you can modify Wordpress's default login form, which is inside wp-login.php, in your root directory. Look for this line: `<form name="loginform" id="loginform" `

Comment: Sorry, still no luck.  Not what I want.